# What are the typical reasons Javascript developed on Firefox fails on IE?

Tags: jquery, firefox, yui, javascript

I developed some javascript enhanced pages that run fine on recent Firefox and Safari. I missed to check in Internet Explorer, and now I find the pages don't work on IE 6 and 7 (so far). The scripts are somehow not executed, the pages show as if javascript wasn't there, although some javascript is executed. I am using own libraries with dom manipulation, from YUI 2 I use YUI-Loader and the XML-Http-Request, and on one page I use "psupload", which depends on JQuery.

I am installing Microsoft Script Editor from Office XP and will now debug. I will also write specific tests now.

What are the typical failing points of IE? What direction I can keep my eyes open.

I found this page, which shows some differences. visit: [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html)

Can you from your experience name some typical things I should look for first?

I will also ask more questions here for specific tasks later, but for now I am interested in your experience why IE usually fails on scripts that run fine in Firefox

*Edit:* Thank you for all those great answers!

In the meantime I have adapted the whole code so that it also works with Internet Explorer. I integrated jQuery and built my own classes on top of it now. This was my basic mistake, that I did not build all my stuff on jQuery from the beginning. Now I have.

Also JSLint helped me a lot.

And many of the single issues from the different answers helped.

Comment: There are no problems with css or styling so far, as I knew that from earlier coding. Only JS problems - karlthorwald

Comment: I will first run JSLint now on all files, there are some that I never adapted.

Comment: "This was my basic mistake, that I did not build all my stuff on jQuery from the beginning." -- it's not going to magically solve all of your cross-browser problems. Search stackoverflow for jQuery and IE, you'll find tons of issues. Best to learn cross-browser scripting yourself so when jQuery or one of its billions of sketchy plugins fails, you'll be able to implement a real working cross-browser solution, and know that it works, and why.

Comment: +1 On no's comment above. You're FAR better off avoiding jQuery completely IFF you're learning javascript - jQuery is incredibly useful if you want to get something complex done quickly and easily, but if you're learning it will shield you from the complexities of understanding how javascript actually works - far too many people seem to know jQuery but haven't got a clue how to write javascript. You didn't make a mistake not building on jQuery originally - you now have a far better understanding of your own code than you would if you had.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Please feel free to update this list if you see any errors/omissions etc.

**Note:** IE9 fixes many of the following issues, so a lot of this only applies to IE8 and below and to a certain extent IE9 in quirks mode. For example, IE9 supports SVG, `<canvas>`, `<audio>` and `<video>` natively, however you must [enable standards compliance mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/same-markup-using-canvas-audio-and-video) for them to be available.

---

##General:

- **Problems with partially loaded documents:** It’s a good idea to add your JavaScript in a `window.onload` or similar event as IE doesn’t support many operations in partially loaded documents.
- **Differing attributes**: In CSS, it's `elm.style.styleFloat` in IE vs `elm.style.cssFloat` in Firefox. In `<label>` tags the `for` attribute is accessed with `elm.htmlFor` in IE vs `elm.for` in Firefox. Note that `for` is reserved in IE so `elm['for']` is probably a better idea to stop IE from raising an exception.

---

##Base JavaScript language:

- **Access characters in strings**: `'string'[0]` isn’t supported in IE as it’s not in the original JavaScript specifications. Use `'string'.charAt(0)` or `'string'.split('')[0]` noting that accessing items in arrays is significantly faster than using `charAt` with strings in IE (though there's some initial overhead when `split` is first called.)
- **Commas before the end of objects:** e.g. `{'foo': 'bar',}` aren't allowed in IE.

---

##Element-specific issues:

- **Getting the `document` of an IFrame**:

  - **Firefox and IE8+:** `IFrame.contentDocument` (IE started supporting this [from version 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581803/contentdocument-for-an-iframe/6582370#6582370).)
  - **IE:** `IFrame.contentWindow.document`
  - (`IFrame.contentWindow` refers to the `window` in both browsers.)
- **Canvas:** Versions of IE before IE9 don't support the `<canvas>` element. IE does support [VML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language) which is a similar technology however, and [explorercanvas](https://github.com/arv/explorercanvas) can provide an in-place wrapper for `<canvas>` elements for many operations. Be aware that IE8 in standards compliance mode is many times slower and has many more glitches than when in quirks mode when using VML.
- **SVG:** IE9 supports SVG natively. IE6-8 can support SVG, but only with [external plugins](https://web.archive.org/web/20090904133747/http://www.planetsvg.com:80/content/svg-solutions-internet-explorer) with only some of those plugins supporting JavaScript manipulation.
- **`<audio>` and `<video>`:** are only supported in IE9.
- **Dynamically creating radio buttons:** IE <8 has a bug which makes radio buttons created with `document.createElement` uncheckable. See also [How do you dynamically create a radio button in Javascript that works in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118693/how-do-you-dynamically-create-a-radio-button-in-javascript-that-works-in-all-brow/119079) for a way to get around this.
- **Embedded JavaScript in `<a href>` tags and `onbeforeunload` conflicts in IE:** If there's embedded JavaScript in the `href` part of an `a` tag (e.g. `<a href="javascript: doStuff()">` then IE will always show the message returned from `onbeforeunload` unless the `onbeforeunload` handler is removed beforehand. See also [Ask for confirm when closing a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858057/javascript-function-on-web-page-close/2858329).
- **`<script>` tag event differences:** `onsuccess` and `onerror` aren't supported in IE and are replaced by an IE-specific `onreadystatechange` which is fired regardless of whether the download succeeded or failed. See also [JavaScript Madness](https://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html) for more info.

---

##Element size/position/scrolling and mouse position:

- **Getting element size/position**: width/height of elements is sometimes `elm.style.pixelHeight/Width` in IE rather than `elm.offsetHeight/Width`, but neither is reliable in IE, especially in quirks mode, and sometimes one gives a better result than the other.

`elm.offsetTop` and `elm.offsetLeft` are often incorrectly reported, leading to finding positions of elements being incorrect, which is why popup elements etc are a few pixels off in a lot of cases.

Also note that if an element (or a parent of the element) has a `display` of `none` then IE will raise an exception when accessing size/position attributes rather than returning `0` as Firefox does.

- **Get the screen size** (Getting the viewable area of the screen):

  - **Firefox:** `window.innerWidth/innerHeight`
  - **IE standards mode:** `document.documentElement.clientWidth/clientHeight`
  - **IE quirks mode:** `document.body.clientWidth/clientHeight`
- **Document scroll position/mouse position**: This one is actually not defined by the w3c so is non-standard even in Firefox. To find the `scrollLeft`/`scrollTop` of the `document`:

  - **Firefox and IE in quirks mode:** `document.body.scrollLeft/scrollTop`
  - **IE in standards mode:** `document.documentElement.scrollLeft/scrollTop`
  - **NOTE:** Some other browsers use `pageXOffset`/`pageYOffset` as well.

    ```
      function getDocScrollPos() {
       var x = document.body.scrollLeft ||
               document.documentElement.scrollLeft ||
               window.pageXOffset || 0,
           y = document.body.scrollTop ||
               document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
               window.pageYOffset || 0;
       return [x, y];
      };
    ```

  In order to get the position of the mouse cursor, `evt.clientX` and `evt.clientY` in `mousemove` events will give the position relative to the document *without adding the scroll position* so the previous function will need to be incorporated:

  ```
   var mousepos = [0, 0];
   document.onmousemove = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (typeof evt.pageX != 'undefined') {
     // Firefox support
     mousepos = [evt.pageX, evt.pageY];
    } else {
     // IE support
     var scrollpos = getDocScrollPos();
     mousepos = [evt.clientX+scrollpos[0], evt.clientY+scrollpos[1]];
    };
   };
  ```

---

##Selections/ranges:

- **`<textarea>` and `<input>` selections**: `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are not implemented in IE, and there's a proprietary "ranges" system in its place, see also [How to get the caret column (not pixels) position in a textarea, in characters, from the start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea).
- **Getting the currently selected text in the document:**

  - **Firefox:** `window.getSelection().toString()`
  - **IE:** `document.selection.createRange().text`

---

##Getting elements by ID:

- `document.getElementById` can also refer to the `name` attribute in forms (depending which is defined first in the document) so it's best not to have different elements which have the same `name` and `id`. This dates back to the days when `id` wasn't a w3c standard. `document.all` ([a proprietary IE-specific property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408424/document-all-vs-document-getelementbyid)) is significantly faster than `document.getElementById`, but it has other problems as it always prioritizes `name` before `id`. I personally use this code, falling back with additional checks just to be sure:

  ```
   function getById(id) {
    var e;
    if (document.all) {
     e = document.all[id];
     if (e && e.tagName && e.id === id) {
      return e;
     };
    };
    e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e && e.id === id) {
     return e;
    } else if (!e) {
     return null;
    } else {
     throw 'Element found by "name" instead of "id": ' + id;
    };
   };
  ```

---

##Problems with read only innerHTML:

- IE does [not support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) setting the innerHTML of `col`, `colGroup`, `frameSet`, `html`, `head`, `style`, `table`, `tBody`, `tFoot`, `tHead`, `title`, and `tr` elements. Here's a function which works around that for table-related elements:

  ```
   function setHTML(elm, html) {
    // Try innerHTML first
    try {
     elm.innerHTML = html;
    } catch (exc) {
     function getElm(html) {
      // Create a new element and return the first child
      var e = document.createElement('div');
      e.innerHTML = html;
      return e.firstChild;
     };
     function replace(elms) {
      // Remove the old elements from 'elm'
      while (elm.children.length) {
       elm.removeChild(elm.firstChild);
      }
      // Add the new elements from 'elms' to 'elm'
      for (var x=0; x<elms.children.length; x++) {
       elm.appendChild(elms.children[x]);
      };
     };
     // IE 6-8 don't support setting innerHTML for
     // TABLE, TBODY, TFOOT, THEAD, and TR directly
     var tn = elm.tagName.toLowerCase();
     if (tn === 'table') {
      replace(getElm('<table>' + html + '</table>'));
     } else if (['tbody', 'tfoot', 'thead'].indexOf(tn) != -1) {
      replace(getElm('<table><tbody>' + html + '</tbody></table>').firstChild);
     } else if (tn === 'tr') {
      replace(getElm('<table><tbody><tr>' + html + '</tr></tbody></table>').firstChild.firstChild);
     } else {
      throw exc;
     };
    };
   };
  ```

  Also note that IE requires adding a `<tbody>` to a `<table>` before appending `<tr>`s to that `<tbody>` element when creating using `document.createElement`, for example:

  ```
   var table = document.createElement('table');
   var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
   var tr = document.createElement('tr');
   var td = document.createElement('td');
   table.appendChild(tbody);
   tbody.appendChild(tr);
   tr.appendChild(td);
   // and so on
  ```

---

##Event differences:

- **Getting the `event` variable:** DOM events aren't passed to functions in IE and are accessible as `window.event`. One common way of getting the event is to use e.g. 
  `elm.onmouseover = function(evt) {evt = evt||window.event}`
  which defaults to `window.event` if `evt` is undefined.
- **Key event code differences:** Key event codes vary wildly, though if you look at [Quirksmode](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) or [JavaScript Madness](https://unixpapa.com/js/key.html), it's hardly specific to IE, Safari and Opera are different again.
- **Mouse event differences:** the `button` attribute in IE is a bit-flag which allows multiple mouse buttons at once:

  - **Left:** 1 (`var isLeft = evt.button & 1`)
  - **Right:** 2 (`var isRight = evt.button & 2`)
  - **Center:** 4 (`var isCenter = evt.button & 4`)

  The W3C model (supported by Firefox) is less flexible than the IE model is, with only a single button allowed at once with left as `0`, right as `2` and center as `1`. Note that, as Peter-Paul Koch [mentions](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#button), this is very counter-intuitive, as `0` usually means 'no button'.

  `offsetX` and `offsetY` are [problematic](https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#mousepos) and it's probably best to avoid them in IE. A more reliable way to get the `offsetX` and `offsetY` in IE would be to [get the position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160144/find-x-y-of-an-html-element-with-javascript) of the relatively positioned element and subtract it from `clientX` and `clientY`.

  Also note that in IE to get a double click in a `click` event you'd need to register both a `click` and `dblclick` event to a function. Firefox fires `click` as well as `dblclick` when double clicking, so IE-specific detection is needed to have the same behaviour.
- **Differences in the event handling model:** Both the proprietary IE model and the Firefox model support handling of events from the bottom up, e.g. if there are events in both elements of `<div><span></span></div>` then events will trigger in the `span` *then* the `div` rather than the order which they're bound if a traditional e.g. `elm.onclick = function(evt) {}` was used.

  "Capture" events are generally only supported in Firefox etc, which will trigger the `div` then the `span` events in a top down order. IE has `elm.setCapture()` and `elm.releaseCapture()` for redirecting mouse events from the document to the element (`elm` in this case) before processing other events, but they have a number of performance and other issues so should probably be avoided.

  - **Firefox:**

    **Attach**: `elm.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture [true/false])`
    **Detach**: `elm.removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture)`
    (`type` is e.g. `'mouseover'` without the `on`)
  - **IE:** Only a single event of a given type on an element can be added in IE - an exception is raised if more than one event of the same type is added. Also note that the `this` refers to `window` rather than the bound element in event functions (so is less useful):

    **Attach**: `elm.attachEvent(sEvent, fpNotify)`
    **Detach**: `elm.detachEvent(sEvent, fpNotify)`
    (`sEvent` is e.g. `'onmouseover'`)
- **Event attribute differences:**

  - **Stop events from being processed by any other listening functions**:

    **Firefox:** `evt.stopPropagation()`
    **IE:** `evt.cancelBubble = true`
  - **Stop e.g. key events from inserting characters or stopping checkboxes from getting checked:**

    **Firefox:** `evt.preventDefault()`
    **IE:** `evt.returnValue = false`
    **Note:** Just returning `false` in `keydown`, `keypress`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `click` and `reset` will also prevent default.
  - **Get the element which triggered the event:**

    **Firefox:** `evt.target`
    **IE:** `evt.srcElement`
  - **Getting the element the mouse cursor moved away from:** `evt.fromElement` in IE is `evt.target` in Firefox if in an `onmouseout` event, otherwise `evt.relatedTarget`
  - **Getting the element the mouse cursor moved to:** `evt.toElement` in IE is `evt.relatedTarget` in Firefox if in an `onmouseout` event, otherwise `evt.target`
  - **Note:** `evt.currentTarget` (the element to which the event was bound) has no equivalent in IE.

Comment: Very, very, very nice list! Thanks to everyone who contributed :)

Answer (score 26):

Check also for commas such as these or similar if any in your code

```
var o={
'name1':'value1',
'name2':'value2',
}
```

the last comma (following value2) will  be tolerated by Firefox, but not IE

Comment: Most good editors should catch this one

Comment: +1, I had this one too often.

Comment: I would give you +10 if I could -- this happens to me all the f'ing time.

Comment: Oh and to add to @SeanJA's comment: I have recently switched to NetBeans which does catch this.

Comment: I lost so many hours on this the first times I did some JS work. Now is the first thing I check! Curse crappy Textmate expansions leaving commas around.

Comment: I *think* IE8 tolerates the commas, but not IE7.

Answer (score 12):

If you stick to using jQuery or YUI as your post is tagged, you should have minimal differences between browsers...that's what the frameworks are for, to take care of these cross-browser differences for you.

For an example, look at the [quirksmode DOM traversal page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_traversal.html), according to it IE doesn't support most things...while true, the frameworks do, for example IE doesn't support `elem.childElementCount`, but in jQuery: `$(elem).children().size()` works to get this value, in every browser.  You'll find there's something in the library to handle 99% of the unsupported cases across browsers, at least with script...with CSS you might have to move to plugins for the library, a common example of this is to get rounded corners working in IE...since it has no CSS support for such.

If however you start doing things directly, like `document.XXX(thing)`, then you're not in the library, you're doing javascript directly (it's all javascript, but you get the point :), and this might or might not cause issues, depending on how drunk the IE team was when implementing that particular function.

With IE you're more likely to fail on styling coming out right than raw javascript issues, animations a few pixels off and that sort of thing, **much** more-so in IE6 of course.

Comment: I understand better now. Yes, I also did such things directly. karlthorwald

Comment: If you are using an IDE like Netbeans you can set the target browsers for your javascript and it will also help out by warning you when you do something that does not appear to be supported.

Answer (score 10):

getElementbyID will also match against the name attribute in IE, but not other browsers, and IE will select whichever it finds first.

example:

```
<script>
 var foo = document.getElementById('bar');
</script>

....
<input name="bar" type="text" />  //IE will get this element
<span id="bar"> Hello, World! </span>  //FF,Safari,Chrome will get this element
```

Comment: sorry for being rude but IE is really ugly

Comment: document.getElementByIdOrNameIGuessWhateverMan(id);

Answer (score 5):

There are loads of things, but one trap I used to fall in was that many browsers accepts JSON without quoted names, while ie6 and ie7 does not.

```
{ name: "Jakob" } // will often work, but not in ie6/ie7
{ "name": "Jakob" } // Better!
```

**Edit**: To clarify, this is only an issue when actual JSON is required, as opposed to an object literal. JSON is a subset of the object literal syntax and is meant as a data exchange format (like XML) which is why it's designed to be pickier.

Comment: Note that this depends on context, an object literal is fine, JSON is not...but for example jQuery doesn't allow invalid JSON at all in their latest release.

Comment: Not my downvote...but you should clarify this for others, then +1 from me.

Answer (score 5):

### [Differing JavaScript Support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Versions)

IE doesn't support (most of) the extensions added to JavaScript since 1.5.

### [New in 1.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.6)

- Array Methods - `indexOf()`, `lastIndexOf()`, `every()`, `filter()`, `forEach()`, `map()`, `some()`
- [`for each ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#Object_Manipulation_Statements)  - iterates values instead of property names.

### [New in 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7)

- Destructuring assignment -- `[a,b] = [1,2]`
- [Iterators and Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)
- `let` and `const` statements
- [array comprehensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions#Differences_to_the_older_JS1.7.2FJS1.8_comprehensions)

### [New in 1.8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.8)

- Array Methods - `reduce()`, `reduceRight()`
- Shortcuts for defining functions.

Some of these things require you to specify a version number of JavaScript to run under (which will break under IE), but some things like `[1,2,3].indexOf(2)` might not seem like that big a deal, until you try to run it in IE

Comment: the JavaScript you are talking about here is mozilla's JavaScript(TM), not javascript in the more generic sense. Not all ECMAScript implementations / javascript engines (MS JScript in this case) should be expected to follow mozilla's JavaScript(TM). ECMAScript is the standard, not JavaScript(TM), and JavaScript(TM) is not javascript. I hope that made sense.

Comment: Makes sense to me, but on a thread about compatibility between JavaScript and JScript, I figured that would be understood already :)

Comment: When you say "IE doesn't support (most of) the extensions added to JavaScript since 1.5.", it sounds like you're saying mozilla's JavaScript(TM) is a standard that IE should adhere to, when of course it's not. You could at least say Mozilla's JavaScript or similar... other browser don't support all of mozilla's extensions to ECMAScript like destructuring assignment, etc. The question was about differences between 'most' `javascript` and (the specific implementation) `JScript`, not differences between `Mozilla JavaScript(TM)` and `JScript`. It might be better to show where IE deviates from ES.

Answer (score 3):

The major differences between JavaScript in IE and JavaScript in modern browsers (ex, Firefox) can be attributed to the same reasons behind the differences in CSS/(X)HTML cross-browser. Back in the day there was no de facto standard; IE/Netscape/Opera fought a turf war, implementing most of the specs, but also omitting some as well as making proprietary specs to gain advantages over each other. I could go on at length, but lets skip ahead to the release of IE8: JavaScript was avoided/scorned for years, and with the rise of FF and the contempt of webcomm, IE chose to focus mostly on advancing their CSS from IE6 on. And basically left DOM support behind. IE8's DOM support might as well be IE6's, which rolled out in 2001....so IE's DOM support is nearly a decade behind modern browsers. 
If you are having JavaScript discrepancies particular to a layout engine, you're best bet is to attack it the same way we took on the CSS problems; Targeting that browser. DON'T USE BROWSER SNIFFING, use feature detection to sniff out your browser/it's level of DOM support.

JScript is not IE's own implementation of ECMAScript; JScript was IE's answer to Netscape's JavaScript, both of which came into existence before ECMAScript.

As far as type attributes on the script element, type="text/javascript" is the default standard (at least in HTML5), so you don't ever need a type attribute unless your script isn't JavaScript.

As far as IE not supporting innerHTML...innerHTML was invented by IE and is still today NOT a DOM standard. Other browsers have adopted it because it's useful, which is why you can use it cross-browser. As far as dynamically changing tables, MSDN says "because of the specific structure required by tables, the [innerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa219845%28office.11%29.aspx) and [innerHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897%28VS.85%29.aspx) properties of the table and tr objects are read-only." I don't know how much of that was true initially, but clearly the modern browsers have figured it out while dealing with the complexities of table-layout.

I highly recommend reading *PPK on JavaScript* 
Jeremy Keith's *DOM Scripting* 
Douglas Crockford's *JavaScript: The Good Parts* 
and Christian Hellman's *Beginning JavaScript with DOM Scripting and Ajax* to get a strong grasp on JavaScript.

As far as Frameworks/Libraries are concerned, if you don't have a strong grasp on JavaScript yet, you should avoid them. 2 years ago I fell into the jQuery trap, and while I was able to pull off magnificent feats, I never learned a damn thing about coding JavaScript properly. In hindsight, jQuery is a wicked awesome DOM Toolkit, but my failure to learn proper closures, prototypical inheritance, etc., not only set my personal knowledge back, my work starting taking huge performance hits because I had no clue wtf I was doing.

JavaScript is the language of the browser; if you are client-side/front-end engineer it is of upmost importance that you command JavaScript. 
Node.js is bringing JavaScript full tilt, I see immense strides taken daily in its development; Server-side JavaScript will be a standard in the very near future. I'm mentioning this to further emphasize just how important JavaScript is now and will be.

JavaScript is going to make more waves than Rails.

Happy Scripting!

Comment: Nice answer, though I don't agree with using feature detection to sniff out the browser; only use feature detection to test for support of *those* features. Also see the examples in [Feature detection is not browser detection](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/12/29/feature-detection-is-not-browser-detection/).

Comment: meh. i completely agree with your disagreement. thanks for catching that. i'm still a JavaScript n00b, but there's no shame in my game.
"Feature-based browser detection is a very bad practice that should be avoided at all costs. Straight feature detection is a best practice, and in almost every case, is exactly what you’ll need."

Answer (score 2):

Trailing commas in arrays and object literals used to be a problem, haven't checked recently (meaning IE8):

```
var a = [ 1, 2, 3, ];
var o = { a:1, b:2, c:3, };
```

This would cause some extra code when generating such structures server side.

Answer (score 2):

Some native objects are read-only without really seeming to be so (you can write to them but it has no effect). For example, a common advanced javascript is based on extending the `Element` object by overriding system methods, say, changing Element.prototype.appendChild() to do more than appending a child node - say, initialize it with parent's data. This will fail silently on IE6 - original method will be invoked on new objects instead of the new one.

Some browsers (I don't remember which now) consider newlines between HTML tags to be text nodes, while others don't. So childNodes(n), nextSibling(), firstChild() and the like will behave very differently.

Answer (score 2):

I just found one this morning, a co-worker set the script tag as:
`<script type="application/javascript">` because his ide autocomplete had that before "text/javascript"

But, it turns out that IE just ignores the entire script if you use "application/javascript", you need to use "text/javascript"

Comment: javascript is default in all browsers, so use just `<script>`

Answer (score 2):

I found an odd quirk just the other day with Internet Explorer.  I was using YUI, and replacing the contents of a table body () by setting the innerHTML

```
Y.one('#elementId').set('innerHTML', '<tr><td>Column 1</td></tr>');
```

This would work in all browsers EXCEPT IE.  I finally discovered that you couldn't replace the innerHTML of a table in IE.  I had to create a node using YUI and then append that node.

```
var myNode = Y.node.create('<tr><td>Column 1</td></tr>');
Y.one('#elementId').append(myNode);
```

That was a fun one to figure out!

Comment: I have a feeling that you need to wrap it with `<tbody>` tags.

Comment: In the original code, it actually is wrapped in a <tbody> tag.  It still blows my mind that IE didn't like it.  I remember reading up on it in Microsoft's official docs, but I can't find the link now.  Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Extra commas and missing commas used to be usual problem on IE while it works smoothly on FF.

Answer (score 1):

IE is very strict about missing ";" so is usually that.

Comment: I find many of these while I am jsLinting now. Seems to be an important point.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth I just came across this nasty issue in < IE9

say you have some html like this:

```
<table><tr><td>some content...</td></tr></table>
```

and for some reason (I had a good one) you need to retrieve all HTML in the table before the last closing TR you might try something like this:

```
var tableHtml = document.getElementById('thetable').innerHTML;
var fragment = tableHtml.substring(0, tableHtml.lastIndexOf('</tr>'));
```

< IE9 will return nothing (-1) here because the tableHtml variable contains all html tags upper-cased and lastIndexOf is case sensitive. To get around this I had to throw in a toLowerCase() before lastIndexOf.

Answer (score 0):

IE is not a modern browser and only follows ECMAScript loosely.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned jQuery which I'm less familiar with but for general reference, and specifically with Prototype, one thing to watch out for is reserved words / method names in IE. I know what often gets me is things like:

`someElement.appendChild(new Element('label',{ **for**: someInput.id }).update( someLabelText );`

(new Element(tagName, propertyHash) is how new elements are created in Protitype). In IE, `for:` must be `'for':`, because `for` is a reserved word. Which makes complete sense -- but FireFox will tolerate this.

Another example:

`someElement.wrap('div').addClassName('someClass')`

(the `wrap` method in Prototype wraps one element in another) -- In IE, on textareas, `wrap` is a property, and `Element.wrap()` must be used instead of the methodized version

These are two examples which come to mind from my experience. They're based on prototype but the core issue isn't: Watch out for any methods/labels/identifiers which IE considers reserved words but FireFox or Safari will tolerate.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that IE doesn't support JavaScript... It supports his own implementation of ECMAScript : JScript... which is kind of different...

Answer (score 0):

Using `console.log()` for outputting errors to the Firefox error console will cause your scripts to fail in IE. Got to remember to take those out when you test in IE.

Comment: I believe using console.log will also fail even in Firefox if you don't have FireBug turned on.