# Yii showing blank page in IE7 and FF on Windows

Tags: internet-explorer, yii

I have an application running on Yii framework which works fine when I view the application on Ubuntu Firefox and Windows Chrome and Safari.

Am experiencing problems while using IE and Firefox on Windows. The application serves a blank page on one particular screen. This screen uses a DB insert and selection and there are no exceptions.

Please note that I am able to view this screen on other browsers. IE shows a blank page with a "JSON is undefined error" Javascript error.

I tried removing the following from my layout file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I also tried disabling DIVX add ons in IE. Didn't work.

I am using a stateful Yii form on this page.

Comment: It sounds like a JS error for sure, which is blocking the page load in IE. Try using the IE Developer Tools to get more details about where the JS error is occurring. Also, check in Google Chrome Console or Firefox/Firebug to see if the error is getting thrown in those browsers as well (and they are just recovering better than IE). Once you debug your JS IE will probably work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I finally figured out the problem. The page was using an Image type button and IE didn't recognize the POST variable !

Answer (score 1):

I made this comment already, but maybe I can get some rep if I post this as an actual answer. ;)

If IE is showing a blank page and you already *know* there is a JavaScript error, then you've found the problem most likely. Often times when there is a JS error IE will fail to load the page, while FF and Chrome will recover and still the load page (although the the scripts might not work correctly).

Try using the [IE Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get more details about where the JS error is occurring. Also, check in the [Google Chrome Console](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/) or [Firefox/Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see if the error is getting thrown in those browsers as well. Once you debug your JS IE will probably work fine.

There is probably an extra comma in an object/array string if I know IE. :) Here is a good place to start learning about why JS fails on IE that is working fine in other browsers:

[What are the typical reasons Javascript developed on Firefox fails on IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599020/what-are-the-typical-reasons-javascript-developed-on-firefox-fails-on-ie)

Good luck!