# Is it possible to write something in a iframe when a button outside the iframe is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am coding some kind of display made of an iframe. When I click a button, which is outside the iframe, it should right something down on the iframe. Is it possible?

```
<iframe src = "display.html" id = "ifr"></iframe>

    <div class = "buttons" onClick = "showSequence()">
        Get the whole sequence
    </div>
```

The javascript code:

`function showSequence(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById("ifr"); 
    (iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document).write("Something!");
}`

Comment: If the iframe is from your domain, and not cross domain, it's very possible.

Comment: does the display.html page exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the iframe is in the same domain.
Here is a code example:

```
<button onclick="test()">Click to write in iframe</button>

<iframe id='ifr'></iframe>
<script>
    function test(){
        var iframe = document.getElementById("ifr"); 
        //contentDocument because IE8 doesn't support contentWindow
        (iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document).write("hello iframe");   
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't forget to include support for browsers that use `.contentDocument` instead of `.contentWindow.document`

Comment: @Ian this is new information for me... do you have any reference about the browsers that support contentDocument?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581803/contentdocument-for-an-iframe . I would use `var iframe = document.getElementById("ifr"); (iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document).write("hello iframe");`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but I can't make it work here :/ Take a look at the code: function showSequence(){
 document.getElementById('pageDisplay').contentWindow.document.write("Something!");
}

Comment: @RenatoBispo Without any of your code, there's no way to help. fmodos provided a way to do it that should work. And you never answered whether the pages had the same domain or not

Comment: @RenatoBispo your code looks fine... what browser are you using? does it show any error? ps: Ian just updated my answer, thanks for the information

Comment: I am using Google Chrome. No, no, it doesn't show any error message. :/ Can't find out why it's not working.

Comment: Ok, I tested your code and it worked for me... did you put the javascript code inside the <script> tag?

Comment: It's an external file. Is that the problem? I know it's well 'linked' because I tested some stuff on it.

Comment: no, it shouldn't be... please check the javascript console on chrome and make sure that there is no error.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'write' of undefined. That's what I got, after that last line. But man, don't worry, you have already helped me a lot, thank you very much. I will keep looking for a solution and then, if I get something, I will post it here later ;D. Thank you all. See you.

Comment: Also got this: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/display.html from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/index.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: oh this happens when opening the html by the physical location, dont know why... but it will work if you put it in a http server like apache and access by an url ie: http://localhost/yourfile.html, I suggest you to create a new post with this question maybe someone else can help you.

Comment: Oh fmodos, I think I got it. I tested your code in a new HTML document, and I noticed that there is no "src" attribute in your iframe tag. But there is one in mine. I deleted this "src" atributte and it worked! Don't know why exactly...