# The iframe "src" attribute issue

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to document.write something inside an iframe. I asked a question about that([Is it possible to write something in a iframe when a button outside the iframe is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578150/is-it-possible-to-write-something-in-a-iframe-when-a-button-outside-the-iframe-i)), and got some answers, but there is a problem: when I add a "src" attribute to the iframe tag, the code stop working, it doesn't write anything in the iframe.

The code below doesn't work:

```
<button onclick="test()">Click to write in iframe</button>

<iframe id='ifr' src = "myDocument.html"></iframe>
<script>

function test(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById("ifr"); 
    //contentDocument because IE8 doesn't support contentWindow
    (iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document).write("hello iframe");   
}

</script>
```

However, if I delet that "src" attribute, it works.

Any ideas about why that happens?

Comment: Use `iframe.open(); and iframe.close();` methods.

Comment: You´re not supposed to manipulate an iframe page. (this would make phishing really easy), I think that's the problem. Also are you running this code locally?

Comment: try to add text to to the body element or some div... `write` will overwrite the contents of iframe

Comment: It's working for me http://jsfiddle.net/k2dPS/

Comment: @EL Iframes don't have `.open()` and `.close()` methods. Their `document`s might...

Comment: Yes, I am running it locally

Comment: @Jochem261 You can manipulate iframes as long as they're in the same domain...which it is in the OP's code...

Comment: @Ian Thats why i asked if he was running it locally. Because you can't do this locally.

Comment: @Jochem261 I was responding to your first sentence as a general comment, because you *can* manipulate an iframe page easily. Locally is different from cross-domain, but both won't work.

Comment: Not sure from your question if this is a question concerning the Same Origin Policy – but easiest thing to do would probably be to just replace the existing iframe element with a new one, http://jsfiddle.net/CBroe/Am26r/

Comment: Thanks @CBroe! That worked even better, because when I click the button again it doesn't add more stuff on it.

Comment: @lan Sorry, forgot to mention `iframe = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument);` before `iframe.open();`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than document.write, you could use the src attribute:

```
var htmlString="<p>Hello iframe</p>";
var ifr = document.getElementById('ifr');
ifr.src="javascript:'"+htmlString+"'";
```

htmlString could be html or just text.

The above technique is equivalent to the srcdoc attribute in html5.