# Iframe without src but still has content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

While debugging jquery code on their site ( via chrome developer toolbar)

I noticed that their examples are given under `Iframe` :

[Here  - for example](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) there is a sample which is under an Iframe but after investigating  , I see that the Iframe  doesn't have `SRC`

The picture shows it all

[image]

**Question :**

Is it possible to set content to an Iframe without setting its SRC ?

p.s. this menu also shows me an empty content

[image]

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to load an empty `<iframe>` (with no `src` specified) and later apply content to it using script.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/js/main.js (line 54 and below).

Or simply try:

```
<iframe></iframe>

<script>
document.querySelector('iframe')
        .contentDocument.write("<h1>Injected from parent frame</h1>")
</script>
```

Comment: $('iframe')[0].contentDocument.write("<h1>Injected from parent frame</h1>") seems to cause the loading icon in the browser Tab to constantly spin.

Comment: use document.close() to close writing

Comment: why do people do it? what's the use-case? you could just append a div or even custom html elements to root body and use inline styling and/or long strange css classes so you are sure nothing collides with existing styling if that's what you want to solve..

Comment: @OZZIE It is used by codepen.io to let the user write CSS and JS code that gets executed in the iframe, then the user can just write the CSS code without it inlining it.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, Here is how you change the html of the iframe with jQuery

```
var context = $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document,
    $body = $('body', context);
$body.html('Cool');
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yBmBa/**

**document.contentWindow: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/d...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk%3aDocument_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/document.contentWindow)**

Answer (score 8):

Looks like this is the most compatible solution across browsers and also it is recognized by the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/fetching-resources.html#about:blank)

```
<iframe src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 7):

There's the [`srcdoc` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp) in `iframe` that allows setting HTML content directly:

```
<iframe srcdoc="<p>Hello world!</p>" src="demo_iframe_srcdoc.htm"></iframe>
```

`src` is for backup in case the browser does not support `srcdoc`.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. You can get a reference to the `iframe`'s `document` object with

```
var doc = iframe.contentDocument;
```

and then you can create and add elements like you do in the current document.

If the iframe doesn't have a `src` attribute, it will still contain an empty document. I believe though that at least older IE versions require the `src` attribute to be set, otherwise the iframe won't have a document.

See also: [contentDocument for an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581803/contentdocument-for-an-iframe).

Comment: If the `src` attribute is set, then yes, the content can only be accessed if the loaded document is from the same domain.

Comment: I wonder why did they do that....it's much easier having small html files being set as SRC rather then getting their content and inject to an iframe.... I really really wonder if there's something behind this decision

Comment: Maybe they want the documentation for a method in a single file but still have some kind of sandbox for each example. But that's just an assumption. You could ask them ;)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, they already have the code loaded in the DIV above the `Iframe`, it's much easier to `eval` that code lines for demo purposes into an Iframe than to create a separate static html for every piece of demo code.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, what do you mean?

Comment: @haim770 look at the viewsource of the page , you wont find any js code which can be evaled

Comment: @Royi: That doesn't matter. You can still exact the text content and you have valid code.

Comment: @FelixKling hu?  I really really dont think they strip the html tags in  order to get the pure js...

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/js/main.js (line 48). they do extract the javascript code from the 'beautified' example and evaluating it (not using `eval` though).

Comment: @Royi: Why should they? They just take the whole HTML in the example and dump it in the iframe. And by just taking the text content of the `div` that holds the source, they get rid of all the syntax highlighting markup.

Answer (score 2):

Try it.

***HTML***

```
<div id="iframecontent" style="display: none;">
    <b>Hello World!</b> <br /> <i>Hello Again !</i>
</div>

<div style="margin: auto; width: 80%;">
    <iframe height="100" width="100%" src="about:blank" name="myiframe"
     id="myiframeid"> </iframe>
    <br />
    <button id="tryIt" onclick="onTryItClick()">Try It</button>
</div>
```

***JavaScript:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onTryItClick() {
    var content = document.getElementById("iframecontent").innerHTML;
    var iframe = document.getElementById("myiframeid");

    var frameDoc = iframe.document;
    if (iframe.contentWindow)
        frameDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

    frameDoc.open();
    frameDoc.writeln(content);
    frameDoc.close();
}
</script>
```

Reference:
http://duleekag.blogspot.com/2014/01/html-iframe-without-src-attribute.html

Answer (score 1):

Try giving :

```
src ="javascript:false;"
```

Comment: I dont think so ,,,http://i.stack.imgur.com/8zghY.png (http://jsbin.com/ezekuw/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Mixing best answers in javascript and jQuery, I come up with this solution for each `iframe` in a page:

```
<div class="iframewrapper ws-s-top mb-50" data-content="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><p>Hello world</p></body></html>">
    <iframe frameborder="0" src=""></iframe>
</div>

$(".iframewrapper").each(function(){
    var html = $(this).attr("data-content");
    var iframe = $(this).find('iframe');
    var context = iframe[0].contentDocument.write(html);
    iframe[0].contentWindow.document.close(); //without this line, page loading animations won't go away!
});
```

Answer (score 1):

And you can even use a data uri as src:

```html
<!-- a zero width space -->
<iframe src="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8;base64,4oCL"></iframe>
<!-- Hello World! -->
<iframe src="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8;base64,SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"></iframe>
```