# How to populate an iframe which an HTML string of a complete document, rather than giving it a link to another web page in the src attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I get an *HTML string* in my Javascript/JQuery script which is the complete HTML of a document. I need to display this HTML inside a `<div>` in my web page.

For example, my Javascript is like:

```
// code ...
var htmlString = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>something</title>...other html tags...</head><body>...</body></html>";
// code...
```

I need to render the html string (the value of `var htmlString`) in a particular `<div>` in my webpage.

My idea is that in order to display an HTML page in another HTML page, we need to use `iframe`. But `iframe` gets a link to that webpage which is hosted somewhere. All I have is the HTML string of a complete HTML webpage, and I need to display it on my webpage in a `<div>`.

How can I do that?

Comment: I can't figure out if you want it in a blank iframe inside the <div> or insert html directly in the <div> itself? Both are possible. Please update question to clear up ambiguity and make objectve more absolute

Comment: `div.innerHTML = html`?

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you, I hope the question is clear now??

Comment: @Luca That will insert a <body> and </body> tag within my page's body etc. I don't think that will work

Comment: @charlietfl What other page? There is no html page, just an HTML string being generated somewhere.

Comment: Oh ok...then do exactly what Luca suggested. or there are other insetion methods like appendchild...prependChild as well. Should be easy to find tutorials on how to insert html into existing page

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you. Another side question: This HTML is actually coming when I fetch HTML of a website using php curl. Then I get it into my JS (to display it) using AJAX. The question is that can I use php curl to also pull the stylesheets and images etc. that the other website, e.g. this stackoverflow page, has?

Comment: Well that's what I meant by "another page". Getting styles and images gets horribly complicated if they don't have absolute paths in href and src or if they have hot link protection on them being served elsewhere. You would also need all that isolated in iframe rather than inject in your own page unless you aren't worried about style conflicts

Answer (score 3):

You can load an empty  with no src and later apply content to it using a script.

```
<iframe></iframe>

document.querySelector('iframe')[0]
        .contentDocument.write("<h1>Injected from parent frame</h1>")
```

See:[Iframe without src but still has content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044073/iframe-without-src-but-still-has-content)
Hope I helped you

Answer (score 0):

if you are having html and you want to show the html as it is obtained then you can use `div.innerText` something like  this

```
<div id='dd'>
</div>

<script>
var htmlString = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>something</title>...other html tags...</head><body>...</body></html>";
document.getElementById('dd')[0].innerText = htmlString;
</script>
```

But if you want only data inside the body to show with all the tags inside it then you can use `innerHTML`
change:

`$('#dd')[0].innerText = htmlString;`

to

`$('#dd')[0].innerHTML = htmlString;`

For working example, you can see the working fiddle at 
http://jsfiddle.net/p793syjq/9/

Comment: I am not sure about the change of title while including your <title> tag in variable will affect or not, you can see it by adding it.

Comment: This won't work with an iframe, and a div can't usefully contain a full HTML document.