# Target window.opener iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I can write something to an iframe like this

```
window.frames[0].document.write(something);
```

But i am trying to write something to an iframe from a opened window within the same domain. I don't know how to target that iframe. I tried something like this:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("iframe").write(something);
```

or

```
window.opener.frames[0].document.write(something);
```

But that didn't work. Any ideas or questions about what i am trying to do?

*The iframe is on the parent window. I try to target that from the opened window

Comment: So to get it clear. You are opening a new window with an `iframe`. And from the parent window (which opened the new window) you want to write something in that new opened window's `iframe`?

Comment: No, I am opening a new window. From that window i try to write something to the iframe on the parent window

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6581896/1427878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `contentWindow` property of the iframe. Try this.

**Parent page**

```
<iframe id="ifr"></iframe>

<button onclick="window.open('child.html')">Open Window</button>
```

**Child.html page**

```
<button onclick="writeToParentIframe()">Write to Parent Iframe</button>

<script>
    function writeToParentIframe() {
        opener.document.getElementById("ifr").contentWindow.document.write("<h1>Hello World</h1>")
    }
</script>
```