# getElementsByClassName not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I was trying to print a anual report but i need to change 2 texts around the page, one of them has only a class attribute. Im new at js so i made this.

```
<div id="formBusqPresElec:dtResBSPE_paginator_bottom" class="ui-paginator ui-paginator-bottom ui-widget-header">
    <span class="ui-paginator-current">Mostrando 1-20 de 1626 registros</span> 
</div>
```

And the other has an id.

```
<div id="fBusqSPE">Mostrando 20 de 1626 registros</div>
```

I made it work on Chrome

```
function imprimir() {
    var oldText = document.getElementById('fBusqSPE').innerText;
    document.getElementById('fBusqSPE').innerText = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-paginator-current')[0].innerText;
    window.print();
    document.getElementById('fBusqSPE').innerText = oldText;
}
```

But in firefox throws

> [10:48:48.330] TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is
>   undefined

Edit: So let me explain more.

Actually im working inside 2 iframes, which the first one is for the menu, and the other one is for more options. Then the central iframe  is used to show the actual report.
Maybe I must define which iframe I want to retrieve those elements.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2SxYS/. Please provide more information/context.

Comment: @MelanciaUK He's using `.getElementsByClassName()`. So that should work.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

Comment: As of [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName) it should work on firefox from Ver. 24.0.

Comment: @Jamiec: Might be that this is an additional problem, but it does not explain the error.

Comment: @FelixKling - comment out the `window.print` and the following line which sets it back - the text is not changing because `innerText` is not supported by FF

Comment: @Jamiec: `innerText` works fine in FF 26 at least. And as I said, it might be an *additional* problem, but `.innerText` won't cause the error `TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined`.

Comment: @FelixKling: That's a new feature for FF 26. FF 25 and earlier doesn't have it.

Comment: If there are no elements with that class name, then the `[0]` reference will be `undefined`.  I suspect that `getElementsByClassName` is returning a perfectly good, but **empty**, node list.

Comment: @BlueSkies: I know that it's not supported in FF. And it turns out that it isn't supported in FF26 either. My first test seemed to indicate that it doesn't but I cannot reproduce it anymore, so... :)

Comment: @FelixKling: And here you had my hopes up that we had another step toward browser compatibility. Darn you Felix Kling! ;-D

Comment: Well, in my FF 25.0.1 document.getElementsByClassName(..) works just fine. @lsxida what version of FF do you test on?

Comment: @fast - I think you've missed the point of this conversation - nobody denies `document.getElementsByClassName` works in all FF's - its `innerText` which doesn't!

Comment: guys i added some extra info. Maybe its because the iframes, i should declare on the document something?

Comment: @Jamiec: reg. the conversation you're right, sure ;-)

Comment: DOM methods, such as `getElementsByClassName`, certainly don't take iframes into account. But it shouldn't work in Chrome either. If you are looking for elements in a specific iframe, you have to get the document object of that iframe first.

Comment: Thanks guys, I wouldnt make it without help.

You're awesome :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems here. The first causes your error of `document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined` and once overcome, the second is that [Firefox does not support innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

The only way to generate the specified error in Firefox is for no elements with the specified class being present on the page. This is demonstrated by the following code

```
<div class="a-test"></div>
// on page load
document.getElementsByClassName("b-test")[0].innerHTML="Test";
```

JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/UL2Xs/

If you watch the console when running the above fiddle, you'll see the same error as you get.

**Is it possible that your javascript is running before the page has finished loading?**

The second, and more minor issue is that FireFox does not support `innerText`. You should use `.textContent` or possibly `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Ty, it wasnt on the page the script.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use:

```
 iframe.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName(...)
```

(see: [contentDocument for an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581803/contentdocument-for-an-iframe))

Answer (score -2):

Basically `.innerText` will not work in FF. FF uses `textContent` property.

```
var text = element.textContent;
element.textContent = "this is some sample text";
```

Comment: How does this explain the error? `TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined`?

Comment: Really? If I change it back to `.innerText`, all I see in the alert `undefined`, but not the error the OP mentions. http://jsfiddle.net/PDf66/1/. `.innerText` is not the reason of the error!

Comment: Ok so tell me what error OP mentioned. You have downvoted my answer?

Comment: If you read the question carefully you will see *"But in firefox throws `[10:48:48.330] TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined`"*. Don't get me wrong, using `.innerText` is incorrect, but it is not responsible for the error and therefore your answer doesn't solve the overall problem.

Comment: And what do you see on the alert?

Comment: That I see `undefined` in the alert has nothing to do with `TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined`. Here is an example of what would happen if the `TypeError` occurred: http://jsfiddle.net/PDf66/2/. As you can see, the `alert` is not even executed.

Comment: A 10 years child would know that the only reason for document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined is that there is no element with this class. Now the iframe things is included in the question. Great ..  and thank you.