# Why does javascript/jquery execute in all browsers but IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm hoping some fresh eyes can see what I'm missing. I have a page (in WordPress site) that works just fine in Firefox, Chrome, Opera & Safari but not in IE. To see if it's even executing anything, I've placed an alert in the first line of the document.ready function and it displays on all the browsers except in IE (tried it on IE7 and IE9).

Here's the document.ready function. Can anyone see any reason why this would not execute in IE?

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('in .ready function');
    //$("input:text:visible:first").focus();
    $(window).scrollTop();
    // $(this).scrollTop(0);
    $("#u_phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
    $('#fab_result').hide();
    $('#fab_header').hide();
    $('#optIn').hide();
    $('div.message').show();
    $('#mymap').show();
    $("#my_form").validate();
    if ($("#u_firstname").length > 0) {
        $("#u_firstname").rules("add", {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            messages: {
                required: " This field is required "
            }
        });
    }
    if ($("#u_email").length > 0) {
        $("#u_email").rules("add", {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            messages: {
                required: " This field is required "
            }
        });
    }
    if ($("#u_phone").length > 0) {
        $("#u_phone").rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: " This field is required "
            }
        });
    }
    if ($("#u_custom_20").length > 0) {
        $("#u_custom_20").rules("add", {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            messages: {
                required: " This field is required "
            }
        });
    }
    var mapsterOpts = {
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        render_highlight: {
            fillColor: '2aff00',
            stroke: true,
            strokeWidth: 2
        },
        render_select: {
            fillColor: 'ff000c',
            stroke: false
        },
        fadeInterval: 5000,
        isSelectable: false
    },
        mainOpts = $.extend({}, mapsterOpts, {
            mapKey: 'province',
            onClick: clickMain
        }),
        detailOpts = $.extend({}, mapsterOpts, {
            onClick: clickDetail
        });
    $('#canada-map').mapster(mainOpts);
});
```

Comment: Press F12 for developer tools.

Comment: What do you mean does not execute? Does the alert at the top fire? Can you paste some information from IE's error console?

Comment: Enable script debugging. Look for syntax errors on a page refresh.

Comment: Does your script create a canvas tag that does not work in your IE browsers? If so wrap it in a conditional tag to check browser

Comment: The `$(document).ready()` gets executed just fine here in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5Htgp/.  If it's not executing for you, then you probably have a javascript syntax error somewhere else in this file that stops the interpreter from even parsing the JS.  You will need to see what is says on your whole app in the console of the IE dev tools (press F12, look at console).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599020/what-are-the-typical-reasons-javascript-developed-on-firefox-fails-on-ie -- Are there any trailing commas in object/arrays? `{willBlowUpInIE:true,}` - There are other reasons listed there

Comment: I should have elaborated. It was late and I was tearing my hair out. To answer some of the questions...<br>No-the alert doesn't fire in IE.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses. The issue DID end up being trailing commas in the following code. Although I had changed it and uploaded to the server, it wasn't recognizing my change because I hadn't updated the WordPress page.

Comment: Grr. Everytime I want to start typing on a new line I hit Enter and it just adds the comment instead of inserting a new line. I don't have a clue how to add a new line in a comment.

Comment: The code was originally like this but once I got rid of the trailing comma and updated the Wordpress page it worked.     messages: {required: " This field is required ",     }

Answer (score -1):

problem is here:

use var to declare variables and do not use comma(,) instead (;)

change this:

```
var mapsterOpts = {
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    render_highlight: {
        fillColor: '2aff00',
        stroke: true,
        strokeWidth: 2
    },
    render_select: {
        fillColor: 'ff000c',
        stroke: false
    },
    fadeInterval: 5000,
    isSelectable: false
},
    mainOpts = $.extend({}, mapsterOpts, {
        mapKey: 'province',
        onClick: clickMain
    }),
    detailOpts = $.extend({}, mapsterOpts, {
        onClick: clickDetail
    });
$('#canada-map').mapster(mainOpts);
```

to

```
    var mapsterOpts = {
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        render_highlight: {
            fillColor: '2aff00',
            stroke: true,
            strokeWidth: 2
        },
        render_select: {
            fillColor: 'ff000c',
            stroke: false
        },
        fadeInterval: 5000,
        isSelectable: false
    };
    var mainOpts = $.extend({}, mapsterOpts, {
        mapKey: 'province',
        onClick: clickMain
    });
    var detailOpts = $.extend({}, mapsterOpts, {
        onClick: clickDetail
    });
    $('#canada-map').mapster(mainOpts);
```

Comment: `var a,b,c,d;` is totally legal - not sure why you'd suggest using multiple vars when the best practice is to only have one `var` per `function`