# How to access elements written by javascript to DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the following code, which writes radiobuttons through javascript to HTML

```
document.write('<input type="radio" name="AnswerA" />' + res.rows[jsonCounter][1]);
```

Say, I want to access this AnswerA field and find out if it's been selected, I can try :

```
    if(document.getElementById('AnswerA').checked) {
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to work - can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The <input> element is missing the id attribute. So document.getElementById('AnswerA') fails.

Comment: `<input type="radio" name="AnswerA" id="AnswerA"  />`

Answer (score 3):

You need to set an `id` on the new DOM element for `document.getElementById` to use:

```
document.write('<input type="radio" name="AnswerA" id="AnswerA" />' + res.rows[jsonCounter][1]);
```

Comment: I tried adding this, but my if statement still doesn't run

Comment: Try adding the input using `document.createElement` instead.

Comment: this works different to document.write, yes? I have to add it to a form I think

Comment: No, you just need a parent element to add it to (which can be the document). See this answer for an example: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1936533/105045](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1936533/105045)

Answer (score 1):

Add id in your DOM element. It will work.

```
document.write('<input type="radio" id="AnswerA" name="AnswerA" />' + res.rows[jsonCounter][1]);
```

Comment: I tried adding this, but my if statement still doesn't run