# Add Radio buttons to Html form using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

In my HTML code I have

```
<form id="approve">
    <input name="myDate" id="monthYearPicker" />
    <button type="button"onclick="monthlytimesheets()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In my Javascript file I have the following:-

```
function monthlytimesheets() {
    $.post('http://localhost:8000/timer/monthly_timesheet/',
        function(returnedData) {
            for(i=0;i<returnedData.length;i++) {
                for(j=i+1;j<returnedData.length;j++) {
                    if(returnedData[i]['id']==returnedData[j]['id']) {
                        returnedData.splice(j,1)
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Now i want my `returnedData[i]['full_name']` rendered on html page as radio buttons. How can i do that. How do you dynamically create radio buttons from JS? Also can i assign values to these radio buttons?

Comment: What will be the value of ` returnedData.splice(j,1)`

Comment: Find some documentation on how append() works. On another note you should put the `returnedData.length` value in a variable instead of recalculating it over and over.

Comment: `$('form').append('<input type="radio" />Radio')`

Comment: @user2181397 returnedData.splice(j,1) returns an array devoid of duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

you can create radio buttons easily using jquery as you want. I wrote a code to show how to create `radio` button `dynamically`. automatically and when a button clicked.change the inside conditions as your needs. try below code.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>


<!-- Example one , add radio button using jquery automatically-->
<h1>Example one , add radio button using jquery automatically</h1>
<form id="approve">
    <input name="myDate" id="monthYearPicker" />
    <div class="lastone"></div>
</form>

<br><br><hr>
<!-- Example two, add radio button using jquery when button click-->
<h1>Example two, add radio button using jquery when button click-</h1>
<form id="approveone">
    <input name="myDate" id="monthYearPicker" />
    

    <div class="lasttwo"></div>
    <input type="button" id="addradio" value="submit">
</form>



</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
      var labelname = "radio button"+i;
      var value = i;
      var create = $('<input type="radio" value="'+value+'"><label>'+labelname+'</label><br>');
      $(".lastone").append(create);
    }

});


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#addradio").click(function(){
    
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
      var labelname = "radio button"+i;
      var value = i;
      var create = $('<input type="radio" value="'+value+'"><label>'+labelname+'</label><br>');
      $(".lasttwo").append(create);
    }


  });
  
});

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create elements dynamically like this

```
var content = document.createElement('div');    
var newElement = document.createElement('input');
newElement.setAttribute('type', 'radio');

newElement.value = "Your value";   ///Here you can assigned value to the radio button

content.appendChild(newElement);
```

Comment: what is newDiv.value ? It is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that returns a radio element. Similar question was already asked.

It can be found here: [How do you dynamically create a radio button in Javascript that works in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118693/how-do-you-dynamically-create-a-radio-button-in-javascript-that-works-in-all-bro)

```
function createRadioElement(name, checked) {
  var radioHtml = '<input type="radio" name="' + name + '"';
  if ( checked ) {
      radioHtml += ' checked="checked"';
  }
  radioHtml += '/>';

  var radioFragment = document.createElement('div');
  radioFragment.innerHTML = radioHtml;

  return radioFragment.firstChild;
}
```

Note that this is the snipped from the answer of the posted link, published by Prestaul.

Would have postet it as comment, but need 50rep to comment...

Answer (score 0):

```js
function monthlytimesheets()
{
 var name = $('#monthYearPicker').val();
 $('#approve').append('<input type="radio" />'+name);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="approve">
    <input name="myDate" id="monthYearPicker" />
    <button type="button"onclick="monthlytimesheets()">Submit</button>
</form>
```